# Is there any simpler syntax for a pimpl implementation like this?

Tags: c++

Is there any simpler syntax for the below pattern? You can do it as described below, but man, it's not terse code for a very simple idea. Is there some library that makes this less awkward or some other pattern I should consider?

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
class abstr
{
public:
    class subclass
    {
    public:
        virtual void x(T) = 0;
    };
    void doThing(T a)
    {
        m_a->x(a);
    }
    abstr(subclass* a)
    {
        m_a = a;
    }
    subclass* m_a;
};

class concr : public abstr<int>::subclass
{
public:
    void x(int a)
    {
        std::cout << "hi!" << a;
    }

};

int main()
{
    concr a;
    abstr<int> r = abstr<int>(&a);
    r.doThing(5);
}
```

Comment: For what other pattern you might want to use, depends on what you problem you need to solve. You haven't told us, why you want to use pimpl in the first place.

Comment: This looks more like strategy pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loki has a pimpl helper:

http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Idioms.Pimpl

But it mostly helps with the pointer management, copy-construction etc. pp. if I remember correctly.
The tedious part is still up to you.

Comment: ugh. With more googling this seems to be the only thing out there.